# Socket.io console.log multiple time

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm currently using Socket.io for one of my project and I have some problem why one of my update.

When I received new datas, I'm making a log in the console (console.log(data)) but the problem is that I don't have one log but 7 to 9 log with the same thing inside it.

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {
  fs.watch( 'example.xml', function ( curr, prev ) {
    fs.readFile( 'example.xml', function ( err, data ) {
      if ( err ) throw err;
      parser.parseString( data );
    });
  });
  parser.addListener('end', function( result ) {
    result.time = new Date();
    socket.volatile.emit( 'notification' , result );
  });
});
```

The result.time is everytime different (just for my test)

Does anyone have the same "problem" and how can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine the problem is everytime a socket connect, you attach a new **"end" event** to the `parser` object.

So, first socket to connect will attach one "end" event. Next socket to connect will attach another one, and because it's [an array of listeners](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.20/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_event_listener), it will be added to the stack, so you will end up with N "end" events, and so on...

When the parsing finish it will emit the "end" event. And if you've attached 2, 3 or more "end" events it will fire N-times. So you have a problem in the logic. You can't attach events on connect to an already initialized object (and probably a singleton one), unless you deal with duplicates.

I suggest you attaching the "end" event outside the io.sockets.on('connection') event, and passing a reference to the socket here, so you know who to send the notification.

```
parser.parseString( data, **socket** );
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: How do you then reference the socket inside the parser.addListener method?